# Sending request header in nightwatchjs

Tags: nightwatch.js

I need to send a specific header called '**Test**', and set it to value of **true**, within my nightwatchjs setup.

This is required so that each test uses this request header in order to work.

I'm wondering how I do this, in which config does it need to be set and how?

Any help would be much appreciated.

thanks